# The adapter items just disappear

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**Video Preview :**

[image]

The views of recycler sometimes disappear from nowhere and sometimes not.

Could someone explain to me why this is happening?

```
    postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(), postList, userPreferences);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);

    pullRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
          Post p = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
          postKeys.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
          postList.add(p);
          postAdapter.notifyItemInserted(postList.size() - 1);

          pullRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
     }
```